# How to pass function as props to a child element in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got a parent navbar component.

```
const Navbar:React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [displayDialog, setDisplayDialog] = useState(false);

  function  doSomething(){
    console.log('do something')
  }

  return (
    <AppBar className={classes.background} position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography className={classes.title}>Labs</Typography>
        <Button onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => setDisplayDialog(true)} className={classes.loginButton}>Login</Button>
        <SettingsMenu doSomething={DoSomething}/>
         //Error is here ^^
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

What I want to do is i wanna pass dosomething as function to the child element. The main function is when clicked there will be an alert or console.log.

here is the error log

> "message": "Type '{ doSomething: () => void; }' is not assignable
> to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<SettingsMenuProps,  never> & {
> wrappedComponentRef?: ((instance: SettingsMenu | null) => void) |
> RefObject<...> | null | undefined; }, any, any>> & Readonly<...> &
> Readonly<...>'.\n  Property 'doSomething' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<SettingsMenuProps, never> & {
> wrappedComponentRef?: ((instance: SettingsMenu | null) => void) |
> RefObject<...> | null | undefined; }, any, any>> & Readonly<...> &
> Readonly<...>'.",

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

type SettingsMenuProps = RouteComponentProps;

type SettingsMenuState = {
  settingsAnchorElement: Element | null;
  currentDialog: null | 'authentication' | 'resetProgress';
  showLoginButton: boolean;
};

type NavbarProps = {
  doSomething: () => void
}

export class SettingsMenu extends Component<
  SettingsMenuProps,
  SettingsMenuState,
  NavbarProps
> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      settingsAnchorElement: null,
      currentDialog: null,
      showLoginButton: false
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <button onClick={this.props.doSomething}>Do Something</button>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(SettingsMenu);
```

Comment: What kind of javascript do you use? React.js or Vue,js or whatever? Pleas add an appropiate tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You specified incorrect generic types in SettingsMenu definition.
Type of props should go in the first generic argument.

Try:

```
type SettingsMenuProps = RouteComponentProps & NavbarProps;

export class SettingsMenu extends Component<
  SettingsMenuProps,
  SettingsMenuState
  > {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      settingsAnchorElement: null,
      currentDialog: null,
      showLoginButton: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.doSomething}>Do Something</button>
    );
  }
}
```